# tableviewcontroller not working when called from other viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have two tableViewControllers created in storyboard:
categories and stores.
When I select a category, it's supposed to show all stores that are in that category.
(I'm getting stores data from server, but I set a fixed category in the url so it should fetch the same two stores no matter what.)

The weird thing is that when I choose a category, storesController shows up empty, 
but if I set it as initial controller, it works.

[StoreTableViewController_as_initial.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVAUD.png)

[StoreTableViewController_from_categories.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QUib.png)

this is how I setup the cells in storeController.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
StoresCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"storetile"];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[StoresCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"storetile"];
}

cell.storelabel.text = [[_results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]objectForKey:@"name"];
[cell.storelabel sizeToFit];
cell.subtitleOneLabel.text=[[_results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]objectForKey:@"neighborhood"];
cell.subtitleTwoLabel.text = [[_results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]objectForKey:@"city"];
NSString *distance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~%@ km",[[_results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]objectForKey:@"distance"]];
cell.distanceLabel.text = distance;
NSString *imgPath = [[_results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]objectForKey:@"imgUrl"];
UIImage *thumb = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://andrafterdevelopment.com.br/apps/buscaabc/img/%@",imgPath]]]];

[cell.thumbImage setImage:thumb];
return cell;
}
```

I break at the return, the method is always called but when it's from categoriesController all labels in my cell are nil.

this is how I call storeController from categoriesController

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSDictionary *item = [_results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
BOOL hasSub = [[item objectForKey:@"hasSub"] boolValue];

    StoreTableViewController *storesTableViewController = [[StoreTableViewController alloc]init];


    //storesTableViewController.title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
    //storesTableViewController.category = (int)[item valueForKey:@"id"];
    [storesTableViewController.tableView registerClass:[StoresCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"storetile"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:storesTableViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I'm guessing this has to do with custom cell or maybe I'm doing it wrong by calling it this way.

Comment: hide **[storesTableViewController.tableView registerClass:[StoresCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"storetile"];** and try once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Storyboard, you should create your controller via Storyboard.
Set `Storyboard ID` in `Identity inspector` for your `StoreTableViewController` and change your method on:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSDictionary *item = [_results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
BOOL hasSub = [[item objectForKey:@"hasSub"] boolValue];

    StoreTableViewController *storesTableViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard id"];
    storesTableViewController.title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
    storesTableViewController.category = (int)[item valueForKey:@"id"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:storesTableViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Or you can use `segues` and configure your `StoreTableViewController` in `prepareForSegue` method:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"StoreTableViewControllerSegureIdentifier"]) {
    StoreTableViewController *storesTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    storesTableViewController.title = _selectedItem.title;
    storesTableViewController.category = _selectedItem.identifier;
  }
}
```

Comment: your second solution works perfectly! I completely forgot / didn't think about prepareForSegue method. I saw one example of tableView using didSelectRow and took it as the only way. thanks man.

Comment: I have other question though. In this case, i connected my cell as push to storecontroller, so it would know where to go, but how do put a condition like if hassub, go to subcategories else, go to stores. segue.identifier is readonly right?

Comment: @Andrews You can connect your view controllers by segue (not cell and view controller) and use method if hassub `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"subcategories  segue id" sender:nil];`  else `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"stores segue id" sender:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have declared `_results` as a property in `StoreTableViewController` right?
If so, change your `categoriesController` method to:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSDictionary *item = [_results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
BOOL hasSub = [[item objectForKey:@"hasSub"] boolValue];

    StoreTableViewController *storesTableViewController = [[StoreTableViewController alloc]init];
    storesTableViewController.title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
    storesTableViewController.category = (int)[item valueForKey:@"id"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:storesTableViewController animated:YES];
}
```

And register cell in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I tried that, but the error remains. 
anyway, the svvoff solution worked for me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Their are few things that i think you should check in your code.

When you are opening second view controller for selected category, did your service giving you data?

If you are getting data, then is it getting filled in array in right way?

And if everything above is fine, then had you called `[tableView reloadData]` method after filling data in array.

Comment: yes, it was getting the data from the service and cellForRowAtIndexPath was being called, but despite setting texts for my labels, they were always nil.
I got it by using @svvoff prepareForSegue solution.
thanks for your time